# Ruby-on-rails - rake db:migrate - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rake

My question is about an error I get when I try to run the command: rake db:migrate on a Linux vm I set up at nitrous.io. I get the error "rake aborted!". Here is a snapshot: 
**~/workspace/myblog$ rake db:migrate                                                                         rake aborted!                                                                                                                            No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)**

I've searched on stack overflow already and found several similar questions and even some answers. However before I try any of the specific responses I wanted to ask my question a bit differently. The reason is the answers seem remarkably varied and likely specific to others environments.

Here are my thoughts:

1. Is the problem as I suspect that my "PATH" settings aren't finding the rake file needed?
2. If so, where can I find ways to fix this in Linux?
3. To get my vm set up I followed some great instructions at: http://railsapps.github.io/rubyonrails-nitrous-io.html
   In so doing I created a directory "myblog" for my app in the workspace        directory as you can see above. Is this good and/or standard practice?

All of this is driven by my work in a Coursera MOOC called "Web Application Architectures". So I'm new to rails and ruby as well as using nitrous.io.

Comment: try bundle exec rake db:migrate

Comment: you need to give the command in a rails app folder. 
give ls command and you should see the Rakefile along with app, bin, config and some other folders.

Comment: Is there a rake file?

Comment: if you look in `~/workspace/myblog`  Do you have a rails app there?